# How do I access this bonfire in Lost Bastille?

Tags: dark-souls-2

[image]

There's lots of rubble in the way but I can't seem to jump over any of it.

I've tried exploring around but haven't found a way to the bonfire.

Any directions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will be taken there by a flying creature, if you sit in a bird nest after the Pursuer boss fight. When you continue onwards from the boss fight, there will be stairs to the right where you see one of those trees with an empty face. You'll find the nest there. You cannot get there any other way.